# Unable to get key event when using uic.loadUI() in PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4

I have the following code that cannot capture the key event.
I used the uic.loadUi() to load my GUI.
But I can't seem to capture the keyboard event.

Pls help!

```
class cMyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("myApp.ui")
        #~ self.ui.show()   # Show myApp UI but key event Doesn't Work :(
        self.show()         # Show a small window but key event works.

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event)==QtGui.QKeyEvent:
            print ("type(event) = ",type(event))
            if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
                print("Esc pressed!!!")
                self.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = cMyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem! ;P

When loading with uic.loadUI(), must supply 'self' as another parameter for baseinstance; otherwise it's default to None.

The corrected codes portion should be:

```
    self.ui = uic.loadUi("myApp.ui", self)  # Must supply 'self' as baseinstance.
    self.ui.show()   # Show myApp UI can work with key event now! :)
```